# VNC or remote desktop application to view Windows desktop from Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop, vnc

I have been looking for a fast, well supported VNC or remote desktop application to view my Windows machine desktop from my Ubuntu laptop. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 24):

You can use the default VNC client for Ubuntu: **Remmina**

Just type *VNC* or *remmina* in the dash to start it:

[image]

Note: It's installed by default since 12.04.

Comment: This seems to no longer be true in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @BrianLeishman You sure, still present in the iso manifest: http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.manifest (`remmina 1.4.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1`)

Comment: Not totally sure, but I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install and it wasn't installed, I had to `apt install remmina`

Answer (score 18):

I've always used KRDC. It just works.

```
sudo apt install krdc
```

Comment: The other suggestions didn't work on 14.04 LTS. This one is great. Thanks.

Comment: This one is so awesome! Everything works! This is the true tool of a remote worker.

Comment: I'd only ever used Remmina. It works, but was sometimes a bit frustrating to set up. KRDC is amazingly simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Some Free/Libre software supporting [VNC/RFB protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol) or [Remote Desktop Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Non-Microsoft_implementations) (RDP):

- [**noVNC**](http://novnc.com) ([GitHub](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC)) is a browser-based app supporting many VNC features but no RDP.
- [**rdesktop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdesktop) ([GitHub](https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop))
- [**FreeRDP**](https://www.freerdp.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP)) Fork of **rdesktop** to clean the code, support *Seamless Windows* (RDP6)...
- [**Remmina**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remmina) ([GitHub](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina)) Based on **FreeRDP** replaced tsclient as Ubuntu's default RD client (2011)
- [**Vinagre**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinagre) Default GNOME VNC client supporting RDP since 2012
- [**Ulteo Open Virtual Desktop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulteo_Open_Virtual_Desktop) (guide to [get source code](https://gist.github.com/jas-/3ee76618b4f056d1a052))

**VirtualBox** has a built-in vRDP protocol that can be used to access GNU/Linux remote desktops (Linux distro usually lacks a RDP server). The vRDP protocol is compatible with all RDP clients. However, the proprietary [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#VirtualBox_Extension_Pack) is required.

See also this good [comparison of remote desktop software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) (Wikipedia).

#### TechRadar has also published an interesting article on this purpose:

https://www.techradar.com/news/5-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients

> **Best Linux remote desktop clients: Top 5 RDC in 2018**
>   By Mayank Sharma, January 2018
>   *We cover all the ins-and-outs of remote viewing*
>
> **Remote control features**
>
> - TigerVNC         **3**/5
> - RealVNC **4**/5             Top
> - Remmina          **4**/5    Top
> - Vinagre     **3**/5
> - TightVNC **3**/5
>
> **Multimedia performance**
>
> - TigerVNC          **4**/5    Top
> - RealVNC **4**/5              Top
> - Remmina          **3**/5
> - Vinagre     **4**/5    Top
> - TightVNC **2**/5
>
> **Interface and usability**
>
> - TigerVNC         **3**/5
> - RealVNC **3**/5
> - Remmina          **3**/5
> - Vinagre     **3**/5
> - TightVNC **3**/5
>
> **Documentation and support**
>
> - TigerVNC         **2**/5
> - RealVNC **5**/5                Top
> - Remmina          **3**/5
> - Vinagre     **2**/5
> - TightVNC **2**/5
>
> **Server and protocol support**
>
> - TigerVNC         **2**/5
> - RealVNC **4**/5               Top
> - Remmina          **3**/5
> - Vinagre     **3**/5
> - TightVNC **1**/5
>
> **Configurable parameters**
>
> - TigerVNC         **2**/5
> - RealVNC **4**/5              Top
> - Remmina          **3**/5
> - Vinagre     **2**/5
> - TightVNC **2**/5
>
> **Connection flexibility**
>
> - TigerVNC         **4**/5   Top
> - RealVNC **3**/5
> - Remmina          **4**/5   Top
> - Vinagre     **2**/5
> - TightVNC **4**/5   Top
>
> **Final verdict**
>
> - [TigerVNC](https://www.tigervnc.org)   **5**/5   Open source credentials and performance
> - [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com) **4**/5   Remote desktop access on the Raspberry Pi
> - [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp)   **3**/5   Multi-protocol remote desktop client
> - [Vinagre](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre)   **3**/5   Lacks the control offered by its peers
> - [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.net) **2**/5   Focus on Windows platforms

Answer (score 8):

Vinagre is now the default client in ubuntu. I had issues with remmina in fullscreen mode, vinagre works as a charm.

Comment: No, vinagre is not the default per se. It depends on the desktop in use. It might be on Gnome and or Unity but it's not on KDE.

Comment: If you install ubuntu and not kubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu/etc. , then it comes by default.

Comment: I had some troubles with strange Alt keys sent to the host using KRDC, after a quick try, Vinagre seems to solve most of them so far!

Answer (score 0):

Best for me is TightVnc - java client to view remote desktop for any vnc server.
You can download directly:
http://www.tightvnc.com/download-old.php
or sudo apt-get install tightvnc
and then 
jtightvncviewer - command line start

Comment: Best for you, why? That would be a more helpful answer.