# VNC Viewer not installing in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, vnc, executable

I installed ubuntu in my virtual machine (Oracle Virtual box) and when i try to install VNC Viewer then it shows:

[image: error message]

when I try to search no applications are found.I could not figure what is wrong here.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post result of `ls -l VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64`

Comment: `64
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 6723160 Mar 23 16:55 VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64`

Comment: Do this `chmod +x  VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64`, then try to install

Comment: @George Thank you very much worked like a charm.Can you explain what was causing the error?

Comment: You were supposed to make the file an executable file before using it. Glad it worked please accept my answer :)

Comment: If you run `ls -l VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64` again you will now see `-rwxrwxr-x 1 george george 6723160 Apr  1 08:02 VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64*`, note the `x` in the result. Meaning the file can now be executed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The process involves two steps:

1. Download the needed files from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/linux/) or any other location.
2. Then make file `executable` with:

   ```
   chmod +x VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64
   ```
3. Then move it to say your `home directory` and run it from there, or any other location:

   ```
   mv VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64 ~/

   ./VNC-Viewer-6.0.2-Linux-x64
   ```

Note: You don't install you just run it.

Source:

https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/linux/

Comment: Yeah and good luck getting an icon in the damn launcher

Answer (score 4):

There are many VNC clients. Some have the same `vncviewer` executable. One is [TigerVNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TigerVNC) which is available in the package manager:

```
sudo apt install tigervnc-viewer
vncviewer <ip>:<display/port>
```

See also: [Best VNC/remote desktop application?](https://askubuntu.com/q/438002/196639/)